# How to render data in react application (if some keys don't have value for older entries)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Let's say i have one table in database named orders and i'm displaying that data in my react application. After 5 months i want add order tracking feature in which multiple columns will be added to orders table which are not present earlier.
So my question is how to handle data in react application. eg.Im displaying recent order in one page in which all orders will be shown. "isDeliver" key was added in process if implementing order tracking feature. So how should i render "isDeliver" value in frontend for older orders.
I can do one thing like if "isDeliver" is not existed for older order then i will not render that text for that order and if it available for new values then i will render that text.
Any one have any other method than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend below solution.

If you could come up with a default value for `isDeliver`, please set that in the database for older orders. This way, data consistency is maintained for all orders.

Best case would be to write a script to update `isDeliver` for older orders based on the status of the order - Whether it's delivered or not.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add conditional casing.

```
const { isDeliver = false } = orders

<div>
{ isDeliver ? isDeliver : 'Value does not exist' }
</div>
```

When you destructure `isDeliver` and if it doesn't exist, you can add a default value which in this case is `false`.